# VueJS data initialization for non existent objects

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using Ajax to populate data properties for several objects. As such, the properties I want to bind to do not exist at the time of binding.

eg:

```
<template>
  <my-list v-bind:dataid="myobject ? myobject.data_id : 0"></my-list>
</template>

<script>
export default {

  data () {
    return {
      myobject: {}
    }
  }
</script>
```

In the Vue docs https://012.vuejs.org/guide/best-practices.html it mentions to initialize data instead of using a empty object.

However I am using multiple Ajax created objects with tens of parameters and sub parameters. To initialize every sub-parameter on all objects like this:

```
myobject: { subp1: [], subp2: [] ...}
```

where myobject may be an object containing array of objects, or an array of objects containing sub-arrays of objects for example.

would take quite a bit of work. Is there a better alternative when binding to 'not-yet existing' objects?

Comment: Is `myobject` supposed to be an array here? Could you clarify what it is supposed to represent?

Comment: @DecadeMoon typically an array of objects but may be more complex - I added some more detail to the question

Comment: It's just confusing because you're binding to `myobject.data_id` but `myobject` is an array (which has no such `data_id` property).

Comment: @DecadeMoon well spotted I have changed declaration to an object, one way to get around this is to bind to the object itself, not the property - but then I am not clear if a watch on props in a child will pick up the addition of a new property.

Comment: you are linking to a very old version of the Vue documentation.... if you really are using v 0.12... you may want to consider upgrading sooner rather than later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, an empty array is still "truthy", so your check here

`v-bind:dataid="myobject ? myobject.data_id : 0"`

always returns true. You should check for `myobject.length` instead. Your code should work now.

Also, you really don't need to define dummy objects for an array. Vue detects whenever you mutate an array.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection

Comment: can I then bind to a non existent property foo.bar that at a later stage when bar exists Vue will honor the bind?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. You're basically asking if Vue supports ajax data, which it does. Keep in mind i'm talking about empty arrays. When you populate an array, Vue steps thru all objects and makes them reactive.